# How to access React (function based) Components functions in Component declaration?

Tags: reactjs

I wondered if its possible to somehow access a React Components function like this on here:

```
const AssetExample = forwardRef(({...props}, ref) => {
  const {view, setView} = useContext(ViewContext);
  return();
}

export default AssetExample;
```

so for example i would need to do the following:

```
<AssetExample setView={(data) => data.hasDefault ? setView('default') : setView('edit')}/>
```

So i would need to overwrite the Behaviour of an Component Function in the Component declaration.

Comment: Fundamentally, no, those functions are entirely private to the component. What is it you're trying to do that makes you think you need to access them? (More: *[What is the X/Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)*) What is `data`? What code would be calling the function you're passing to `AssetExample` as a prop?

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you are describing is exactly what `useImperativeHandle` is made for. Check out the docs here to see if that matches your needs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code, first is that why would you have a context inside a component but you're passing a props that is always set (not null or undefined)?

Anyways to answer your question, you can just do this:

```
const AssetExample = forwardRef(({...props}, ref) => {
  const {view, setView} = useContext(ViewContext);

  const viewFunction = props.setView ? setView;
  return();
}
```

This is the important line:

```
  const viewFunction = props.setView || setView;
```

you can also write it as:

```
  const viewFunction = props.setView ? props.setView  : setView;
```

Then you can just use the `viewFunc` for your function

Answer (score 0):

To override a component function in its declaration in React, you can use the concept of prop drilling or passing functions as props.

In your example, you have a component called AssetExample which receives a prop called setView. You can pass a function as the setView prop when you use the AssetExample component.

For instance, you can do something like this:

```
<AssetExample setView={(data) => data.hasDefault ? setView('default') : setView('edit')} />
```

In this example, you're passing an arrow function as the **setView** prop. This arrow function takes **data** as an argument and conditionally calls **setView('default')** or **setView('edit')** based on the condition **data.hasDefault**.

Inside the **AssetExample** component, you can then use **props.setView(data)** to call this function and pass the necessary data.

Remember, for this to work, you need to ensure that **setView** is a valid function in the scope where you're using **AssetExample**. It needs to be defined and accessible in that context.